# Does a power series with $\infty$ radius of convergence uniformly converges on $\Bbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-c)^n$ be a power series with $\infty$ radius of convergence. In this case, is there any conclusion that will $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-c)^n$ converges uniformly on $\Bbb R$? (I can't find such theorem in my analysis books.) For example, is $1+x+\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\cdots$ converges uniformly on $\Bbb R$ (not just on a closed bounded interval)?

Comment: In general the series is not uniformly convergent in $\mathbb{R}$. In your example, the sum is $f(x) = e^x$, and $\sup |e^x - s_n(x)| = +\infty$ for every $n$ (being $s_n$ the partial sum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless it is a polynomial, the summands don't converge to $0$ uniformly on $\Bbb R$ (if $a_n$ is nonzero, then $a_nx^n$ is unbounded), so the series doesn't converge uniformly on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Why does $a_nx^n$ unbounded imply not being uniformly convergent?

Comment: If $S_n$ converge uniformly, $S_{n+1}$ also, so the difference converges uniformly to $0$ by triangle inequality.

Comment: I see. Thank you all!